# Order by value of Custom Field using url string

Tags: wp-query, order, sort

I have a simple dropdown:

```
<select class="dropdown-class" name="sort-posts" id="sortbox" onchange="document.location.search=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option disabled selected >Select option</option>
        <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == 'date' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'DESC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="?orderby=date&order=DESC">Newest</option>
        <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == 'date' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'ASC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?>  value="?orderby=date&order=ASC">Oldest</option>
        <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == 'title' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'ASC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="?orderby=title&order=ASC">A-Z Asc</option>
        <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == 'title' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'DESC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?>  value="?orderby=title&order=DESC">A-Z Desc</option>
        <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == '50' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'ASC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="?meta_key=budget&orderby=50&order=ASC">Price Under $50</option>
        <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == '199' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'ASC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="?meta_key=budget&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=199&order=ASC">Price $50-199</option>
        <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == '200' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'ASC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="?meta_key=budget&orderby=200&order=ASC">Price Over $200</option>
        </select>
```

and a WP_Query:

```
    $search_result = get_field('search_results', 'option', false);
$args4 = array(
    'post_type'      => array('post', 'tools', 'recipes', 'page'),
    'post__in'  => $search_result,
    'orderby' => get_query_var('orderby'), 
    'posts_per_page'         => '12',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',

);
```

I'm trying to get the query to SORT by a single value when selected, but still show the other posts after.

So for example, Any posts with the custom field (Checkbox) selecting: "50" would display all those posts, in alphabetical order, first - and then the remaining posts after, in alphabetical order.

Likewise, if the dropdown for 199 was selected, the first posts displayed would be those with 199 selected in the custom field checkbox, and then the remaining would display alphabetically after.

I've seen a lot of posts here, but they all seem to do the filtering in the WP_Query args, but I'm hoping to do it via the URL string if possible (because I have already got the dropdown setup and working for date/title).

I've tried:

```
?meta_key=budget&orderby=50&order=ASC
```

and

```
?meta_key=budget&orderby=meta_value&key=50&order=ASC
```

Thanks!

EDIT:  I've also tried this:

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $wp_query ) {

// do not modify queries in the admin
if( is_admin() ) {
    return $wp_query;
}

    // allow the url to alter the query
    if( isset($_GET['budget']) ) {  
        $wp_query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');    
        $wp_query->set('meta_key', 'budget');
        $wp_query->set('meta_value', $_GET['budget']);  
    } 

// return
return $wp_query;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

and set the string to:

```
?budget=199&order=ASC
```

Doesn't work either :(

Comment: WordPress won't parse the `meta_key` in the URL query, unless if you use the `query_vars` filter to add `meta_key` to the public query vars. But then, you should know that the results (by default) will only include posts that have the specified metadata. Also, you should use `orderby=meta_value_num` if the meta value is numeric.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - any chance you could post a corrected version of my code so I can understand more fully what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, I can post an answer, if you still need help with the query string thing. But looking at the question's edit, have you tried a lower priority (i.e. a greater number) - `add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 99);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try use get_query_var instead of $_GET and also increase priority

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $wp_query ) {

// do not modify queries in the admin
if( is_admin() ) {
    return $wp_query;
}

// allow the url to alter the query
if( isset(get_query_var( 'budget' )) ) {  
    $wp_query->set('meta_key', 'budget');
    $wp_query->set('meta_value', get_query_var( 'budget' ));  
} 

// return
return $wp_query;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 11);
```